how to get the type of input when using on handler
I have a form like this:
<form name="filter">

  <input type='number'>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="range">

</form>

I want to get the type of input i use but i do not succeed in it
$(document).on('input', 'form[name="filter"]', function () { 
     alert(this.type); // alerts undefined
});

Based on the input i use, i expect an alert like: number, text or range, but i got "undefined"
What i am doing wrong?

In your code, this refers to the form

You need to add parameter & use like this to get input type.


$(document).on('input', 'form[name=filter]', function(input) {
  console.log(input.target.type)
});
<form name="filter">
  <input type='number'>
  <input type="text">
  <input type="range">
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>




Alternative you can use it by getting event parameter from the function
  $(document).on("input", 'form[name="filter"]', function (event) {
       console.log(event.target.type);
  });


$(document).on('input', 'form[name="filter"] input', function (event) {
    alert(event.target.type);
});

